# VSCode Java 17 cannot find projects

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

After I upgraded to Java 17 (from 11), VSCode, with the java [pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack), will no longer recognize java projects.

[image]

It is a maven project, with a pom file in the root folder and then multiple projects below, like the three shown in the picture above.

It recognizes the maven part just fine, but no java projects.

I tried:

- Setting the JAVA_HOME variable
- Setting the "java.jdt.ls.java.home"
- Setting a config in "java.configuration.runtimes"

What can I do to make VSCode recognize my java projects?

Comment: Any exceptions in the logs? https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/wiki/Troubleshooting#enable-logging

Comment: @ShengChen there is this in the vscode developer console: https://pastebin.com/3FNhGanz

The java language server log has a "container creation failed", but I guess that is expected as it looks for a pom in a single project that isn't there, but that shouldn't stop all projects from being recognized.

Comment: If you try to open only one of the projects, will vscode recognize it as a Java project?

Comment: @JialeDu no, it does not recognize. The only thing I can get working is if I create a new project with the "command:java.project.create" for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the the maven.userSettings in settings.json did the trick!

```
"java.configuration.maven.userSettings": ".mvn/settings.xml",
```

For some reason this wasn't needed when I used Java 11, but now with Java 17 it apparently doesn't find it automatically.

EDIT:
My mistake, it can find it, I was missing the settings file in my .m2 folder, after putting it there, I don't need to set the path as above.

So yea, either put the settings file in  the home/.m2 folder or set the  `java.configuration.maven.userSettings`

Comment: @JialeDu I will, but I am not allowed to accept my own answer before 24 hours has passed.

Answer (score 0):

***Possible workarounds***

Add the following configuration to the **settings.json** file

```json
    "java.jdt.ls.vmargs": "-Xlog:jni+resolve=off",
```

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work for me, still no luck.
Thank you for your suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

In my case i found that the `.project` file was missing the following:

```yaml
<buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
```

and

```yaml
<natures>
        <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
```

I came to this conclusion after creating a new project in the Java Project area, and comparing the files.

There were also entries missing in the `.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs` file, but adding them didn't fix the problem until I added the above.